# Jmeter and vpn connection

Tags: http, jmeter, vpn, http-proxy

I have an app on mobile which runs through VPN connection . I am doing performance testing using jmeter on desktop for which I have done necessary configurations  but http proxy server does not record my http requests

Can anyone help on this

Comment: This might help `jmeter.bat -H <your proxy address> -P <your proxy port number> -u <your vpn user name> -a <your vpn password>`

Answer (score 2):

JMeter and mobile device need to be on the same network in order for JMeter to be able to capture mobile device traffic. So the easiest option would be connecting desktop to the same VPN and using VPN-originated IP addresses.

You will also need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate, the relevant file is `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`, it's being generated in JMeter's "bin" folder when you start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. The easiest way to get the certificate installed onto mobile device is sending it to yourself by email, opening the email on the mobile device and following system dialog to install the certificate.

References:

- [HTTPS recording and certificates](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

---

There is also an alternative solution for recording native and hybrid mobile applications traffic. Using it you won't have to bother about proxies and certificates. As a little bonus, this 3rd-party JMeter Cloud recorder has "SmartJMX" mode with automatic correlations of any dynamic parameters so you won't have to extract them yourself. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) guide for details.